# Why do headphones/speakers go quiet when bass is played?

Tags: windows, audio, speakers, music, headphones

Its happened to everyone, your playing an awesome song, then the drop comes and everything goes quiet.

**Why is it that cheap headphones/speakers are unable to play low bass sounds?**

And why don't they just keep playing what they can, why does it go quiet?

Comment: This is technically off topic since headphones are electronic devices and are not specific to computers, software or networking. You may want to check out [What is Frequency Response?](https://www.headphonezone.in/pages/headphone-frequency-response). The likely reason they go quiet is they are not capable of the frequency response required by the music being played.

Comment: This is off topic, but what you are describing is aggressive compression (NOT "encoding" compression) and/or dynamic range adjustment. Compression usually brings the quiet sound up in volume and can seem like the loud parts "duck." Disable all loudness, compression, dynamic range in your hardware. I recently watched a movie on cable-on-demand that had such aggressive ducking I had to stop watching. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ducking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside of those headphones is a cone, that cone is responsible for moving air at the frequency that the music is playing. For example, a certain part of the song might be oscillating the cone at 100Hz or 100 times/second. As we all know songs don't just have one sound the whole song. The frequency could be changing or you could have multiple frequencies. That's why you can hear both, for example, a clarinet and a trombone. Base tends to be very low frequency and at higher voltage. Those cheap, as you said, headphones may only be able to play, for example, over 100Hz @ a certain voltage. So when the base drops, per-say, the specification of the headphones are being maxed out. Depending on how maxed out they are, they could either give up or blow.